# How to send JS variable to php iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have this variable on my form

```
<script>
     var type = 2;
</script>
```

and on the same page I am calling this iFrame

```
<iframe src='http://www.genpowerusa.com/crm/formal_quote_new2.php' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

What I am unsure is, how could I send the variable to the php form and use the variable on the quote form, the variable is static, I have two pages that call the same iFrame.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: PHP will have finished execution before the browser even sees the `<script>` tags. You might want to look into using AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign an ***id*** to your iframe:

```
<iframe id='foo' src='http://www.genpowerusa.com/crm/formal_quote_new2.php' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Add a js line:

```
document.getElementByid("foo").src='http://www.genpowerusa.com/crm/formal_quote_new2.php?type='+type;
```

What this does is,pass your variable as a PHP url parameter.You can access it by using the following code in php:

```
$type=$_GET['type'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending information via javascript to a frame that is not in the domain of the scope is not possible, because of [cross site scripting](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). That would not be secure (e.g. imagine inserting an iframe with Facebook and grabbing some data from the frame...).